# Interploating a csv file

Tags: online-resources

I have a CSV with me consisting of a few x-y coordinates. How can I form an equation for the graph using these points?

Comment: Least squares regression (Assuming this is real data and not specifically picked as the points of a well-known function).

Comment: @JackPfaffingerDoes least squares work for non linear data?

Comment: Yes, you can look up "Polynomial least squares" if you care about the theory. Otherwise, your options are to put it into Excel or Google Sheets and find a regression option. There are some numpy methods that can do this as well if you can program.

Comment: Alright Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do an xy plot in a spreadsheet you can ask it to add trendline.  You have a choice of linear, polynomial, log,  or exponential.  You can then format trendline and ask it to show the equation.